# Does GDAX have weekl buy and sell limits?

Tags: gdax

I understand that CoinBase has weekly buy and sell limits. Does GDAX have this as well?

Answer (score 1):

No.

From the GDAX support page ([source](https://support.gdax.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2426595-gdax-limits-for-deposits-withdrawals-trades-and-balances)):

> Deposit (BTC, ETH, LTC): Unlimited
>
> Deposit (ACH or SEPA): Varies
>
> Deposit (USD via wire): Unlimited
>
> Trade: Unlimited
>
> Balance: Unlimited
>
> Withdrawal: $10,000/day for individual accounts and $50,000/day for
>   institutional accounts. To be considered for higher withdrawal limits,
>   please go to your Settings within GDAX and click "Increase Limits."